# textarea that can stretch outside of its parent?

Tags: html, css

I'm looking at a reddit.com subreddit post page and it looks like the textarea's on the submit page can stretch outside of the parent div.

I've looked and looked and I don't see how they're doing that.  Here's a good example if you have a reddit login:  http://www.reddit.com/r/summonerschool/submit?selftext=true

You can grab the textarea handle on the bottom right and stretch it to the right past the edge of the parent.

Does anyone know, in general, how you get this effect?

Comment: That's your browser's behavior.

Comment: The textarea handle is the browsers behavior.  Some subreddits allow it to stretch past the parent and some don't (in the same browser), so I know there's some CSS specific trickery that's setting the limits on the width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's effect of resize:both;

Check this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resize

Comment: If you look at the live demo you'll see the 'inside' textarea can't stretch outside of its parent.  In the example I gave it can, this is the behavior I'm trying to discover.

Comment: that's spot on exactly what I'm looking for.  Can you explain the details of how/why that works?

Comment: That's an internal browser behavior but something similar can be achieved by position:absolute of the child: http://jsfiddle.net/pLw8hyct/

Answer (score 0):

Here are few ways you can do it:

http://www.devign.me/css-stretch-a-box-to-its-parent-bounds/
http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/
http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

You simply need to use the box-sizing property.